# How to render a object to template view using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a sample array from data

```
data() {
   return {
      states: [{id:1,name:"AL"},{id:2,name:"AK"},{id:3,name:"CA"},{id:4,name:"TX"},{id:5,name:"WI"},{id:6,name:"WY"}]
   }
}
```

...
and view template

```
<template>
   <div :id="states[2].id">
       This is California - {{ states[3].name }}
   <div>
</template>
```

I want render a object from array (id: 3), but result not work. I don't want to use v-for in this part.

Error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"`

I try again with indexOf() but result not work, too

Comment: [This works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNo9kU1vwyAMhv8K8mmTGqK12w4omxT1NG3HStsUcmANWakCQUC6SVH+e00TgnywH4M/XkYoraWXQQKDwh+dsuGVG/lvexdII1sxdIGM3BDSiCDu7mefOBkGZ5YAjw8iSM9INaqGPWyM0JJxKD84TJuItit6T2iX0L5M6DGhw1dCTwl9viX0vKJvRPVthImb2Yp8XQKDILXtcDKM8FLRqAthqnnhMM9bbWuqGg5zGs/hpDxB24tOtb0zSpCMjOOyXrWraWxNJmyE5XKsh0+LfG0DG1A6SpdpYenZ9wZlvYnEl4TnwJJsHFD3GHM4hWA9y3PfHuNnnD3t3W+OHnWDCUpLKr3Oflz/56XDwhxiibgyTFfcM5XP) fine. Be careful of closing your second `div` tag. There may be other issues unrelated to what you have shared there so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method or computed property and return filtered state, and use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for error:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      states: [{id:1,name:"AL"},{id:2,name:"AK"},{id:3,name:"CA"},{id:4,name:"TX"},{id:5,name:"WI"},{id:6,name:"WY"}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    state(id) {
      return this.states[id]?.name || 'no state'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <div :id="states[2]?.id">
       This is California - {{ state(3) }}
   </div>
</div>
```